# Select the link (a) of third div with CSS styling

Tags: html, css

This is my html code here :

```
<div class="one">
<p><a href="http://www.one.com">one</a></p>
</div>
<div class="two">
<p><a href="http://www.two.com">two</a></p>
</div>
<div class="three">
<p><a href="http://www.three.com">three</a></p>
</div>
```

and my problem is that i want to change color of the **third**  tag that is under third div.
what to do with this ?

Comment: try .three a {color: red}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code :

```
body div+div+div a:hover
{
    color:red;
}
```

OR simply :

```
.three {

color:red;

}
```

---

### DEMO : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/455KB/)

Answer (score 0):

If your third div has a `.three` class applied just use

```
.three a {
    color: ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
div+div+div a:hover{color:green;}
```